# VS Code - syntax highlighting for gitmessage

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have a vscode set up as a git message writer. So far so good. But this month in our company we started using the Phabricator with hashtags, and i cannot use `#` for comments anymore. I've changed it to `|` in gitconfig file  (`commentChar = |`) but from now vscode doesn't recognize syntax.

In the case of vim I managed to change the syntax by editing "/usr/share/vim/current/syntax/gitcommit.vim".

Can I somehow edit syntax highlighting for VS Code?

Maybe there is some option to automatically detect the comment char?

Or should I go back to love vim?

Comment: I don't know if this thread and this specific message will help you: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84201#issuecomment-555521863

Comment: Thx. As I see not only I have the same problem, and solution is not yet provided.